# Getting error while using FDMB sqlite wrapper for iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am getting an error while compiling when I use FMDB wrapper for sqlite. The error is

"_sqlite3_open_v2", referenced from:
-[FMDatabase openWithFlags:] in FMDatabase.o
symbol(s) not found
collect2: Id returned 1 exit status

I just added the classed and havent started working with it.Any help to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're linking to the SQLite library!  In the left pane of your project window in Xcode, expand Targets, click on your target, and command-i to get info.  Under the "General" tab you will see "Linked Libraries".  Verify that libsqlite3.0.dylib is in the list here, and if not, click the "plus" icon and add it.

Comment: Yes it is there already. I was using sqlite before which was working fine. I have already added the framework libsqlite3.0.dylib